# How do you solve these types of related rates questions?

Tags: calculus

A man lifts a bucket of cement to a scaffold $11$ m above the ground by means of a rope that passes over a pulley on the scaffold.

If he walks away from beneath the pulley at $2$ m/s, while keeping his end of the rope at a constant distance of $1$ m above the ground, how fast is the bucket rising when he is $12$ m away from a point directly below the bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assume that the vertical speed of the bucket is the same as the speed at which the amount of cord (call it $z$) between the pulley and his end of the rope increases (that is, the cord is not elastic). If you make a drawing (you get a triangle where $z$ is the hypotenuse) you can see that  $z=\sqrt(10^2+x^2)$, where $x$ is the horizontal position. Taking the derivative of $z$ with respect to time, you get the speed $v_z$, which is the rate they ask, as a function of both $x$ and $v_x$, that you have.

Comment: thank you so much ^_^ but a diagram would've helped alot

Comment: the answer I got is 1.536 m/s , not sure if that's the right answer or not, is that what you got !!!. Thanks again you helped a lot thou

Comment: yes, I've got the same answer: well done! about the graphics, I don't know to do one here. But I can describe it. Make a horizontal line, the floor. Draw a point at height=11 (the pulley. Draw the rope (which is 21 m long: 11 up to the pulley, 10 down to the guy's hand which is 1 meter above the floor. That is the initial position.

Comment: Then, draw the system at an arbitrary position after the guys start to move. Call the position x (horizontal distance from the pulley), you can imagine a triangle defined with vertices 1) at the pulley,2) 1 m above the floor and below the pulley, and 3)the current position of the hand, at a horizontal distance x from the pulley and 1 m above the floor. The triangle has sides of lenght 10 (the vertical side), x (the horizontal side) and z the oblique side that goes from the pulley to the hand. IT is rectangular triangle where z is the hypothenuse, that is how you get the equation for z

Comment: that's exactly what i did :D , thought it was wrong thou :P thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it :)

Comment: you are welcome!